# Wiki.js and self-signed cert for RDS in AWS

Tags: postgresql, ssl, amazon-rds, self-signed-certificate

My org is attempting to deploy Wiki.js in AWS and connect to RDS (using Postgres) in AWS using a self-signed certificate. I am looking at the AWS documentation and don't see any direct references to being able to use anything but the AWS cert bundle. Has anyone used a self-signed cert to connect to RDS in AWS and if so, where did you find the documentation or how were you able to connect to RDS using the cert?

Comment: RDS provides a CA-signed cert (over the connection), and the CA cert (for download).  Why not just use them?